# How to display Time Tracking fields in Issue Detail View using Kanban Board in Jira?

Tags: kanban, jira, timekeeping

That's it. How can I have Time Tracking fields (Original Estimate, Remaining Estimate) show up in Issue Detail View when using a Kanban Board (in "Work" mode) in Jira?

Looks like this feature can only be enabled when using a Scrum Board.

I ask this because I'm very new to Agile and Scrum (and Project Management in general) and I just started working in a new firm as Project Manager. So I'm still learning Jira and gradually introducing the team to new practices. I think a Kanban approach is less invasive but I'm keeping a Scrum Board of the same issues at the same time (luckily they seem to stay quite in sync).

Comment: A feature request is filed at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-13525

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware that you can. It is a long awaited feature for Jira that I have voted on in the ticket referenced in the thread that Vadim has linked.

The way I get around this on one project is to use 'sub-boards' for different roles. Not each team member needs to see what everyone else is doing all the time and may only need to see a small section. So if appropriate, I can make a scrum board for that team with a sub-set of columns, that way the main board is clean and friendly using Kanban, but a smaller board can see the estimates and time remaining etc.

So as an example, say I have a reasonably complicated project on a Kanban board that has around 15 columns and about 20 statuses. That board overviews the entire project through a number of steps: writing stories/scoping, design, API dev, software dev, testing, release. Each of those sections of the process are carried out by a number of different teams and like anyone each team wants a really clear view of what they are working on, but also to see how the whole project is progressing. I could set up my boards roughly like:

Overview board - Kanban and all statuses
User story board - Kanban and first 5 columns
Design board - Scrum board and 3 columns
API dev board - Scrum and 3 columns
Software dev board - Scrum and 3 columns
Testing - Kanban and 3 columns
Release - Kanban and 3 columns

The other trick is that you don't have to call the columns the same thing in each board. So, the done column for design can be the to-do column for API dev.

It's not the most elegant solution, but until Jira possibly update to allow the time-tracking within a Kanban board its working for us as a workaround.

Comment: Update: Jira have now added the ability to add the original and remaining estimate to the card layout on the Kanban board. Configure board>>Card layout>> and add up to 3 fields to the card layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of top Google results:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/283083/time-tracking-feature-in-jira-agile-kanban-board-issue-detail-view

Comment: Be nice please: http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, it is more of a time tracking option on top: http://cronforce.com/blog/cronforce-releases-jira-time-tracking-add-on/

Answer (score 0):

Pick any issue on the Kanban board and edit it
Click 'Configure Fields' in the top right corner
The field you need will not be shown. Click 'Where Is My Field'
At this point, you will need to *know* the name of the field, which is 'Time Tracking'.
Type the field name and presss enter.
You will be presented with some instructions and a link. Follow the link to the Configure Field Screen.
Scroll down to the bottom of the page to the Add section. Again, you will need to know the name of the field you are adding.
Type in the name of the field and click 'Add'
The time tracking fields will then appear on the issue screen.